# Working with R and QGIS

Tags: qgis-modeler

I am performing an interpolation in R but i get the following results. What could be the issue?
The script

```
##MySript=group
##rainfall= vector
##output= output raster
    require(sp)
    require(rgdal)
    rainfall
    slotNames(rainfall)
    rainfall@proj4string
    rainfall@data
    att.table = rainfall@data
    class(att.table)
    dim(att.table)
    dimnames(att.table)
    summary(rainfall)
    plot(rainfall)
    require(geoR)
    require(sp)
    require(maptools)
    require(raster)
    require(geoRglm)
    require(rgeos)
    require (rgdal)
    locs=pred_grid(c(35.06,35.72), c(-1.63,-1.0), by = 0.002)
    data1=as.geodata(rainfall)
    plot(variog(data1, uvec=seq(0,1, by = 0.05)))
    LE1=likfit(data1,cov.model="matern",ini=c(0.0002,0.06), 
         nugget =0.000002,kappa=1.5)
    KC = krige.control(type = "sk", obj.mod = LE1)
    sk1 = krige.conv(data1, krige = KC, loc = locs)
    map=image(sk1)
```

The result

```
require(geoR)
Loading required package: geoR
--------------------------------------------------------------
Analysis of Geostatistical Data
For an Introduction to geoR go to http://www.leg.ufpr.br/geoR
geoR version 1.7-5.2 (built on 2016-05-02) is now loaded
--------------------------------------------------------------

    require(sp)
    require(maptools)
    Loading required package: maptools
    Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
    require(raster)
    require(geoRglm)
    Loading required package: geoRglm
---------------------------------------------------------

A Package for Generalised Linear Spatial Models


geoRglm version 0.9-11 (2017-10-17) is now loaded

-----------------------------------------------------------



require(rgeos)
Loading required package: rgeos
rgeos version: 0.3-26, (SVN revision 560)
GEOS runtime version: 3.6.1-CAPI-1.10.1 r0
Linking to sp version: 1.2-7
Polygon checking: TRUE

    require (rgdal)
    locs=pred_grid(c(35.06,35.72), c(-1.63,-1.0), by = 0.002)
    data1=as.geodata(rainfall)
    plot(variog(data1, uvec=seq(0,1, by = 0.05)))
    variog: computing omnidirectional variogram
    LE1=likfit(data1,cov.model="matern",ini=c(0.0002,0.06), 
           nugget =0.000002,kappa=1.5)
---------------------------------------------------------------
likfit: likelihood maximisation using the function optim.
likfit: Use control() to pass additional
arguments for the maximisation function.
For further details see documentation for optim.
likfit: It is highly advisable to run this function several
times with different initial values for the parameters.
likfit: WARNING: This step can be time demanding!
---------------------------------------------------------------
likfit: end of numerical maximisation.
KC = krige.control(type = "sk", obj.mod = LE1)
sk1 = krige.conv(data1, krige = KC, loc = locs)
krige.conv: model with constant mean
krige.conv: Kriging performed using global neighbourhood
map=image(sk1)


writeRaster(output,"C:/PHDproposal/R_spatial/R_Spatial Exx/data/map.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
Error in writeRaster(output, "C:/PHDproposal/R_spatial/R_Spatial Exx/data/map.tif", :
object 'output' not found
Execution halted
```

Comment: Did you try with `##map= output raster`?

Comment: looks like you haven't defined `output`. But you really should take the time to properly format your code if you're trying to get good help.

Comment: @aldo_tapia yes but i get the same error response

Comment: @bwp8nt thank you for the comment. i have defined but i still get the same response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

```
##output= output raster
```

in an R processing script in QGIS that means that at the end of the script QGIS will use R to save a raster from an object called `output` that you have generated in your script. So for example, if you have:

```
m = matrix(runif(16),4,4)
output = raster(m)
```

in your script then QGIS will create a 4x4 raster at coordinates (0,0) to (1,1), and that will become a layer in QGIS. This is what the `writeRaster` line in the error is doing. It fails because you didn't create a raster object called `output` in your script.

What you did do was `map = image(sk1)` which draws an image, which isn't what a processing script should do if you want it to output a new raster layer. You possibly want to convert the `sk1` object to a raster package "raster" object called `output`.

You can create a raster from `krige.conv` output this way - I'm using the example from `help(krige.conv)`:

```
 > library(raster)
 > output = rasterFromXYZ(cbind(loci, kc$predict))
```

replace `loci` with your prediction coordinates (as a 2-column matrix) and `kc` with your output from `krige.conv`. If you want the kriging variance then use `kc$krige.var`.

I think if you want your processing script to return two raster layers to QGIS, then have two `##` directives naming two R objects, and then do something like:

```
  ##pred= output raster
  ##pvar= output raster

   # insert code here...

  pred = rasterToXYZ(cbind(loci, kc$predict))
  pvar = rasterToXYZ(cbind(loci, kc$var))
```

Comment: Thank you. sk1 is the prediction data and locs is the prediction grid. Possibly if i can call the matrix that joins the data to the grid, i will achieve the intended result which should be an image.

Comment: in R image(sk1) gives and image of values in the prediction grid "locs" which is what i would wish to get in QGIS so that i can use this information with other images

Comment: @ Spacedman
When I try the Bayesian method in R for QGIS using “output = rasterFromXYZ(cbind(locss, skb$predict))” in the script below, I get a miss match  error. I also realize “locss” has 1056 elements and “sbk ” has 2000 elements. How do I use rasterFromXYZ in this situation?

Comment: locss=pred_grid(c(35.06,35.7), c(-1.63,-1.0), by = 0.02)
MC <- model.control(trend.d = "1st", trend.l = "1st",cov.model="matern",kappa = 1.5)
PC <- prior.control(phi.discrete = seq(0, 0.05, l = 40), phi.prior = "reciprocal", tausq.rel.prior = "unif",
tausq.rel.discrete = seq(0, 0.005, l = 20))
OC <- output.control(n.post = 2000, moments = T)
skb <- krige.bayes(data1, loc = locss,model = MC,prior = PC,output = OC)

Comment: That sounds like a new question, and hard to show in comments here. Make a new question with a clear R example, take out the references to QGIS and just ask how to create a raster from the output of `krige.bayes`.

Comment: i have reposted